# Commas in plurals of numbers (1000s vs. 1,000s) in web writing

Tags: grammatical-number, numbers

Would I use a comma within the number 1,000 when expressing it as a plural? For example:

*The laboratory contained 100s or even 1,000s of rats.*

vs.

*The laboratory contained 100s or even 1000s of rats.*

Chicago Manual of Style dictates that these kinds of numbers should be spelled out (*hundreds or even thousands of rats*), but in web style, numerals are almost always preferred. I'm also working with a very small space, so spelling out the number isn't an option.

Note that this question differs from previously answered questions in that it refers to plurals of numbers.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a comma? As someone who trained as an accountant 55 years ago, one of the first things I learned was the importance of writing figures clearly, lining them up properly when tabulating, and ALWAYS USING COMMAS. And if there is one OCD disorder that I express it is about numbers which are sloppily written without commas. It causes error and confusion.

Comment: What is web writing?

Comment: @tchrist Spidery scrawl.

Comment: Why not just say, *lots of rats*? *Hundreds or thousands* is so imprecise that there is little loss of information in replacing it by *lots*.

Comment: "*in web style, numerals are almost always preferred.*" What is *web style*? Does it have a manual? If not, you can do whatever you feel is best. Personally, I find the 2nd version (without a comma) more readable.

Comment: No style guide I have ever seen would recommend using numerals to write these numbers. And for good reason—it looks terrible, and it's misleading. Just write them out. You're saving a total of eight characters. How tight can your space possibly be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chapter 12 (“Numerals”)<sup>*</sup> of
the [*U.S. Government Printing Office (GPO) Style Manual*](http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/GPO-STYLEMANUAL-2008/pdf/GPO-STYLEMANUAL-2008.pdf)
(a 467-page PDF document) has a dozen pages on how to write numbers,
and yet I can’t find anything in it explicitly answering this question. 
The closest I could find was paragraph 12.14, “Punctuation” (on page 289)
which says,

> The comma is used in a number containing four or more digits,
>   except in serial numbers, common and decimal fractions,
>   astronomical and military time,
>   and kilocycles and meters of not more than four figures pertaining to radio.

and, since your case isn’t one of the listed exceptions,
it looks like they specify that you should use the comma. 
However, I noticed that
paragraph 12.9(l), “Measurement and time” / “Percentage”⁠ (on page 287)
says you can use either “**a** 1,100-percent increase”
or “**an** 1100-percent increase.” 
They don’t explain this;
I guess it’s because “1,100” is pronounced “one thousand one hundred”
and “1100” is pronounced “eleven hundred.”
___________
<sup>*</sup> Chapter 12 begins on page 283.

Comment: My company typically uses the Chicago Manual of Style since it tends to be more pertinent for web writing (no spiders, only Internets!), but the GPO style manual is also officially on the books as a reference. Neither of the two seems to have a definitive answer on this one. My inclination is to put the comma in, but the stakeholder wants to leave the comma out. Since there isn't a rule anywhere I can find, I guess I'll defer to the stakeholder. Thanks for your answer. The part about "a" vs. "an" does seem to imply that either could be correct—it is a very interesting example.

Comment: @NicoleL You can always write to the CMoS and ask them—in my experience, they're usually quite good at getting back to you with their views on edge cases that aren't mentioned outright in the guide. (Though here my bet would be that they would say spell it out.)